# Find Key/Value in a Map object and return respective Value/Key

Tags: java, android

I have a map object with Keys/Values defined as US State/Capital (e.g Texas/Austin)

When the user type a State I need to return the Capital and when the user type type a Capital i return the state

I have coded the following but it works only in the Capital -> States comparison.

Any idea on what's wrong?

```
public class StatesCapitals extends AppCompatActivity {

    Map<String, String> capitals = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_states_capitals);

        String text = "US_states"; //text file in the assets folder

        byte[] buffer = null;

        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = getAssets().open(text);
            int size = is.available(); //size of the file in bytes
            buffer = new byte[size]; //declare the size of the byte array with size of the file
            is.read(buffer); //read file
            is.close(); //close file

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        // Store text file data in the string variable
        String str_data = new String(buffer);

        //Split using the delimiter ":" to the all elements
        String[] stateCapsArray = str_data.split(":");
        //Iterate over the array
        for(int i=0;i<stateCapsArray.length-1;i++) {
            //Skip each other element as we are collecting 2 elements at a time
            if(i%2 == 0) {
                String state = stateCapsArray[i];
                String capital = stateCapsArray[i+1];
                capitals.put(state, capital);
            }
        }

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), capitals.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void doit(View v)
    {
        TextView result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
        EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String input=et.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Input: "+input, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Iterator entries = capitals.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
            String key = (String)entry.getKey();
            String value = (String)entry.getValue();
            if (input.equals(key))
            {result.setText("The Capital of "+key+" is: "+value);}
            else if (input.equals(value)) {result.setText("The State of: "+value+" is: "+key);}
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What does the data look like in the file? Can you give us an example?

Comment: Create two maps, one for each direction, or google "[Java Bidirectional Map](https://www.google.com/search?q=Java+Bidirectional+Map)".

Comment: Alabama:Montgomery:
Alaska:Juneau:
Arizona:Phoenix:
Arkansas:Little Rock:
California:Sacramento:
Colorado:Denver:
Connecticut:Hartford:
Delaware:Dover:
Florida:Tallahassee:
Georgia:Atlanta:

Comment: Thank you. I found the error while copy/pasting the input file. There was a " " char because of the line break. I fixed the input. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in the loop:

```
String[] stateCapsArray = str_data.split(":");
for(int i=0;i<stateCapsArray.length-1;i++) {
    //Skip each other element as we are collecting 2 elements at a time
    if(i%2 == 0) {
        String state = stateCapsArray[i];
        String capital = stateCapsArray[i+1];
        capitals.put(state, capital);
    }
}
```

If `str_data` holds information like `state1:capital1:state2:capital2:state3:...` then your loop should iterate through it as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stateCapsArray.length; i += 2) {
    String state = stateCapsArray[i];
    String capital = stateCapsArray[i+1];
    capitals.put(state, capital);
}
```

The main change is that `i` advances by `2` on every iteration.